# Making a pacman game and not sure how to remove pac pellets after colliding with

Tags: python, list, pygame, element, del

I'm currently making a pacman game and am struggling to figure out how to remove a pelllet from the screen after colliding with it. I tried changing the colour to black, but I couldn't make it work. I next tried to `del` the element index, but that also didn't work.

```
import pygame
import os
import sys


#initialise the game 
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((448, 576))
done = False

y = 416
x = 232

#sets up clock and loads pacman image
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
PACMANSPRITE = pygame.image.load("pacman.png").convert_alpha()
PACMAN_MAP = pygame.image.load("pacman_map.png").convert_alpha()

#gets pacman intro music, sets music to lower volume then plays it
pygame.mixer.music.load('pacman_beginning.WAV')
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.01)
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)


#box class, used for boxes to border pacmans map
class boxcollisions(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 12, 12)
        self.colour = (0, 128, 255)

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)

class pointclass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 12, 12)
        self.colour = (255, 204, 153)
        self.score=0

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, self.rect)

    def addpoint(self):
        self.score+=1
        print(self.score)
        self.colour= (0,0,0)
        print('why isnt it working')

#pacmans class
class pacman(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        self.image = image
        self.y=416
        self.x=216
        self.currentx=self.x
        self.currenty=self.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = self.x
        self.rect.top = self.y
        self.rect.width=16
        self.rect.height=16

    # move pacman 
    def movement(self):
        pressed= pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= 2
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += 2
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= 2
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += 2
        self.rect.left = self.x
        self.rect.top = self.y

    def draw(self, surface):
        # blit yourself at your current position
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        self.currentx=self.x
        self.currenty=self.y

    def outofbounds(self):
        self.y=self.currenty
        self.x=self.currentx
        self.rect.left = self.x
        self.rect.top = self.y

#instances the pacman class
sprite = pacman(PACMANSPRITE, x ,y)


#main game loop
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()


    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(PACMAN_MAP, (0, 0))

    #co-ordinates for boxes to set up map boundaries
    boxboundaries=[   
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28],
        [1,14,15,28], #5
        [1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,28],
        [1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,28],
        [1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,28],
        [1,28],
        [1,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23,24,25,26,28], #10
        [1,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23,24,25,26,28],
        [1,8,9,14,15,20,21,28],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28],
        [6,8,9,20,21,23], #15
        [6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28],
        [1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,28],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28],
        [6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28], #20
        [6,8,9,20,21,23],
        [6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28],
        [1,14,15,28],
        [1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,28], #25
        [1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,28],
        [1,5,6,23,24,28],
        [1,2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23,24,26,27,28],
        [1,2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,23,24,26,27,28],
        [1,8,9,14,15,20,21,28], # 30
        [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,28],
        [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,28],
        [1,28],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28],                   
      ]


    #point spawn locations
    pointspawns=[ 
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27], #5
        [2,7,13,16,22,27],
        [2,7,13,16,22,27],
        [2,7,13,16,22,27],
        [2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27], 
        [2,7,10,19,22,27], #10
        [2,7,10,19,22,27],
        [2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,22,23,24,25,26,27],
        [7,22],
        [7,22],
        [7,22], #15
        [7,22],
        [7,22],
        [7,22],
        [7,22],
        [7,22], #20
        [7,22],
        [7,22],
        [7,22],
        [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27],
        [2,7,13,16,22,27], #25
        [2,7,13,16,22,27],
        [2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,25,26,27],
        [4,7,10,19,22,25],
        [4,7,10,19,22,25],
        [2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,22,23,24,25,26,27],
        [2,13,16,27], # 30
        [2,13,16,27],
        [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27],                       
      ]

    #moves pacman
    sprite.movement()

    px=0
    py=-16

    for row in pointspawns:
        #y co ordinate
        py=py+16    
        for n in row:
            #x co ordinate
            n=n-1
            px=n*16
            point=(pointclass(px, py))
            #used to draw points
            point.draw(screen)
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite, point):
                point.addpoint()


    #builds the boxes
    bx=0
    by=-16


    for row in boxboundaries:
        #y co ordinate
        by=by+16    
        for n in row:
            #x co ordinate
            n=n-1
            bx=n*16
            box=(boxcollisions(bx, by))
            #used to draw boxes for visual repsentation
            #box.draw(screen)
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite, box):
                sprite.outofbounds()



    #draws pacman
    sprite.draw(screen)


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know (and I don't know a lot) is using `pygame.sprite.Group()` and `pygame.sprite.spritecollide`.

The basic logic here would be, create a sprite group for the pellets, create every pellet as a sprite and add it to the group. On every iteration of the game loop, draw the sprite group to the screen and validate if there was collision between the player character and any of the pellets in the pellets group with `spritecollide`.

spritecollide has a paramenter to eliminate the pellet when there is collision, so you want to set that to true, in order to avoid drawing it in the next loop.

```
#Basic logic as example.

pellets = pygame.sprite.Group()
#CREATE PELLETS AND ADD THEM TO THE pellets sprite group.

player = Sprite()

...

#IN THE GAME LOOP

    #Validate if there was a collision.
    pellets_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, pellets, True) #True indicates that, if there were any hit, remove the pellet from the group.

    if len(pellet_hit):
        #Increment score or something.

    ...

    #Updating the display
    player.draw(screen)
    pellets.draw(screen) #If there were any hit, the pellet won't be in this group and won't be drawn
```

This is a project example that uses sprites and sprites groups:
[Snake game](https://github.com/antorqs/snake)

Comment: ill try doing it in 10 minutes, thank you for the help

Comment: it doesnt work at all, is IF len(pellet_hit): mean to be just left like that? also how exactly do i make my pellets a group, do i declare pellets as a group and then add the pellets everytime thier drawn or something? thanks for your help aswell

Comment: the `if` statement yes, it is meant to be left like that. See `spritecollide` takes out the hit pellets from your pellets group and adds them to the pellets_hit list so `if len(pellets_hit):` means "if there is something inside the pellets_hit list" or "if any pellet was hit". For the second part, in your case, you add the pellets at the beginning (before the game loop) and every time you call `pellets.draw` it will draw all the sprites inside the sprites group.

Comment: i see, im not sure my code will work like that though as i have a list of co-ordinates for my pellets to be drawn, im not sure i would be able to just draw my pellets so easily but ill give it a go, thanks again

Comment: See, when you use sprites, every sprite has a `rect` property that contains a `x` and `y` value. So when you create every pellet, you define each `x` and `y` value, then add the pellet to the group and then call the group's draw method. I'll update my answer with a tutorial and an example code.

Comment: i still couldnt get it to work :(, ill make sure to comment if i do though, thanks for all your help

Comment: hey @antorqs , i managed to do it, thanks for all the help, i appriciate it, i answered my own question if your curious as to how

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out after a lot of work

```
#spawn pellets function
def spawnpellets(pointspawns):
    abc=0
    efg=0
    px=0
    py=-16
    for row in pointspawns:
        #y co ordinate
        py=py+16    
        for n in row:
            #x co ordinate
            n=n-1
            px=n*16
            point=(pointclass(px, py))
            #used to draw points
            point.draw(screen)
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite, point):
                tempfunc(pointspawns, row, n , py)

def tempfunc(pointspawns, row, n, py):
    abc=n+1
    efg=py/16
    efg=int(efg)
    tempindex=row.index(abc)
    del pointspawns[efg][tempindex]
    pointspawns[int(efg)].insert(abc,0)
```

essentially, i had to put the spawning of the pellets into a function ,and then the collsions detection as another function, then using the vaules or row and n in my for loops i worked out the exact list and indexes i need to use, i then replaces the element with a 0 to have be redrawn no where. sorry if the code lookes a bit jimbled and im aware my variable names are terrible, but i literally just finished this now after 2 hours so im now going to take a well deserved break